# Computing dimension of subspaces of cubics

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

Let $L,M,N \in \mathbb{P}^5$ $3$ general subspaces of codimension $3$, and let $l_i$ (resp $m_i,n_i)$, $i=1,2,3$ be three general points on $L_i$ (resp. $M_i,N_i)$.

I can't understand why $I_{L\cup M\cup N}(3)$, (i.e. the space of all cubics through these subspaces with all first partial derivatives vanishing at this $9$ points), has dimension $26$.

I really can't figure out how to attack the problem, so any hint would be appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

The dimension of the space of cubics passing through $L$, $M$, and $N$ without extra first derivative conditions at $l_i$, $m_i$, and $n_i$ is 26. And if you impose these extra conditions, the dimension will drop to 17.

To see this note that for a general triple $L,M,N$ there is a unique $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$ such that
$$
L = \mathbb{P}^2 \times \{0\},
\quad
M = \mathbb{P}^2 \times \{1\},
\quad
N = \mathbb{P}^2 \times \{\infty\}.
$$
Cubics in $\mathbb{P}^5$ cut out a complete linear system $\mathcal{O}(3,3)$ and the space of cubics containing $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ has dimension 16.

The ideal of $L \cup M \cup N$ in $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathcal{O}(0,-3)$, so the space of sections of $\mathcal{O}(3,3)$ vanishing on $L \cup M \cup N$ coincides with $H^0(\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}(3,0))$, hence has dimension 10. Altogether, this gives
$$
16 + 10 = 26
$$
cubics through $L$, $M$, $N$.

If you want to impose the first derivative conditions at nine points $l_i$, $m_i$, $n_i$, this means that the above section of $\mathcal{O}(3,0)$ vanishes at the corresponding nine points of $\mathbb{P}^2$, and such section is unique. This gives
$$
16 + 1 = 17
$$
as the answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701409.pdf (bottom of page 9) says that $I_{L\cup M\cup N}(3)$ (with singularity at the 9 points) has dimension 26: maybe I misunderstood the theorem, and unfortunately I don't have enough background to understand your proof and see why should work. May I ask you to give a look (and, if it's not a problem, to give a proof of your statement about why $dim(I_{L\cup M\cup N}(3))=26$), in order to full accept your answer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the paper.